# higher order fix point in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml, higher-kinded-types, fixpoint-combinators

What are all the possible implementations the following second-order example in OCaml ?
Here is some very simple Haskell code exhibiting a `fold`, aka the universal property of the initial algebra `FixH`.

I imagine it's easy to make it with OCaml functors.
What are the other options ?

Is there any known implementation with "lightweight higher order kind" style ?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype FixH t a = FixH {unFixH :: t (FixH t) a}

type Tnat f g = forall a. f a -> g a

class FunctorH t where
  hmap :: Tnat f g -> Tnat (t f) (t g)

foldFixH :: forall t f. FunctorH t => Tnat (t f) f -> Tnat (FixH t) f
foldFixH alg = alg . hmap (foldFixH alg) . unFixH
```

Comment: Some good reading https://okmij.org/ftp/ML/higher-kind-poly.html

Comment: I did read it. however it's not quite clear to me what options there is for second order. I should re-read it again. Btw, I don't think it's an opinion-based or vague question however it's not a closed one either. there are multiple answers. anyone can feel free to add their own way if they know one. it's ok not to be exhaustive (and the collection of answers will be of value to future readers)